# Relational Database SQL Query in Asp.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
public async Task<List<Note>>ShowAssigned()
{
 return await _context.Notes
           .Where(x => x.List.OwnerId != x.OwnerId)
           .ToListAsync()
}
```

I get no syntax εrrors, but it seems you can't access attributes from related Data in this way.

Basically the **goal** is: A user creates a List, then some Notes for this List. Then he should be able to assign one of that Notes to another User. When that other User logs on, he should be able to see that new Note that was assigned to him.

Can anyone help me out with this?

```
public class List
{
    public Guid ListId { get; set; }
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }
    public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}



public class Note
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ListId")]
    public Guid ListId { get; set; }
    public List List { get; set; }
}
```

And the context class:

```
public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
public DbSet<List> Lists { get; set; }
```

When i try to access Data the same way in a view like that:

```
 @model List<Project.Models.Note>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.List.OwnerId == item.OwnerId)
```

i get this error when running the web app (no syntax errors):
    NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer to my problem, in some parts with the help of TanvirArjel (but i basically did it differently)

```
 public async Task<List<Note>> GetAssignedItemsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {

        var lists = await _context.Lists.Include(l => l.Notes).Where(x => x.OwnerId != user.Id).ToListAsync();

        var notesListe = new List<Note>();

        foreach (List l in lists)
        {
            foreach (Note n in l.Notes)
            {
                if (n.OwnerId == user.Id)
                {
                    notesListe.Add(n);
                }
            }
        }
        return  notesListe;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**First write your model classes as follows:**

```
public class List
{
    public Guid ListId { get; set; }
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Note
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("List")] // Not ListId, its List
    public Guid ListId { get; set; }

    public virtual List List { get; set; }
}
```

### If your project is on ASP.NET Core < 2.1

**Then write your query as follows:**

```
await _context.Notes.Include(n => n.List).ToListAsync()
```

### If your project is on ASP.NET Core >= 2.1

**Then in the `ConfigureServices()` method in `Startup` class:**

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Don't forget to install appropriate version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` nuget package because `UseLazyLoadingProxies()` resides in this package.

**Then write your query as follows:**

```
await _context.Notes.ToListAsync()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I changed my classes, and now i get `Update-Database : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.` on migration (i wanted to create a fresh database)

Comment: @Nolan now I am out of my computer! I shall be available after half an hour. Then give me Team Viewer Id and Pass, I shall solve your problem! I can assure you that no wrong in my code. Problem is in project configuration may be. By this time you can try your best.

Comment: _// You don't need OwnerId anymore because it already exists in List class. You can remove it if you want_ Thing is, it should be possible to assign a new owner to the notes, while the coressponding List should keep it's owner

Comment: Then don't remove it!

Comment: the Problem basically is to display the Notes that were assigned to another Owner but are still part of a List who's Owner no longer has access to it (because of beeing assigned). As the ListId is not nullable as foreign key, i can't just set it to Null. Maybe set it to a specific persistent Guid, that is the same for all items that were assigned to another Owner?

Comment: strangely, after reopening and rebuilding it worked now

Comment: i only want to put Notes in the List, which coressponding List has an owner that isn't the current user (=the current, new owner of the Note). I think that isn't achieved with `await _context.Notes.Include(n => n.List).ToListAsync()` is it? I tried to achieve that with  `.Where(x => x.List.OwnerId != x.OwnerId)`

Comment: @Nolan, Can you give me remote access?

Comment: sorry, i am at workspace (as intern), i can't do that @TanvirArjel  :(

Comment: Understood!  Now tell me clearly what you are wanting and what is not working!

Comment: Ok @TanvirArjel  The goal is: A user creates a List, then some Notes for this List. Then he should be able to assign one of that Notes to another User. When that other User logs on, he should be able to see that new Note that was assigned to him.

Comment: whats not working is: i can't read via _context.Notes.List properties of the List like OwnerId

Comment: @Nolan  _context.Notes.List is not correct approach. Here Notes is a list and DbSet. First you have access a single Note then You can access List of that Note.

Comment: but if i wanted to gather all the Notes that got assigned to a user (from different Lists and different users) and display them in a view? why does `return await _context.Notes
               .Where(x => x.List.OwnerId != x.OwnerId)
               .ToListAsync();` not work? @TanvirArjel

Comment: @Nolan Is ownerId the user id?

Comment: `await _context.Notes.Inlude(x=>x.List).Where(x => x.OwnerId == userId).ToListAsync();` Try this. Cannot say anything more without seeing your code.

Comment: @Nolan Add full controller method where you are querying the Notes.

Comment: thanks @TanvirArjel I'll try that tomorrow. The ownerId of the already assigned note is the user.id (=current user), because otherwise he would not be allowed to see it

Comment: I also had the Idea to just delete the assigned Note from the table and add it to a new table that has Notes without the ListId attribute

Comment: Add your full controller method first..never ever post partial code.

Comment: added the full controller method @TanvirArjel

Comment: thanks @TanvirArjel your comments helped me find the solution

Comment: @Nolan Share it here!